# Telegram Bot — изменить сообщение пользователя

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Использую `pyTelegramBotAPI`. Можете привести пример кода для бота с админскими правами на изменение сообщения именно пользователя в групповом чате? Например, что бы править нецензурные выражения и тд.

Такой вариант:

```
bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id, text="Я люблю жизнь!")
```

возвращает ошибку:

```
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message can\'t be edited"}']
```

Comment: Никто не может редактировать сообщения пользователя кроме него самого

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в самом групповом чате телеграма, нужно дать боту эти права (сделать администратором). А по умолчанию, бот может редактировать свои сообщения.

Comment: Права у бота максимальные: http://prntscr.com/mc0b9i https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaodQ.png

Comment: Поправка, дело в том, что бот не имеет доступа к сообщениям. По моему мнению, не получится сделать эту затею .